Dynamically changing the rendering of different elements in EJS
I am using EJS, express and axios to pushing over an array called `data` containing all the data to be rendered. I am looping over the data array to render it and that's working.
The problem is I want to be able to click on each item and then pass over the key or index of that item to another element, so I can render that element with the data of with that specific index. When I click on one of the items though, I get a error saying data is not defined in the browser console.
I am guessing that is probably because it can't see the variables from the script tag but I tried some other ways and it just would update the data.
Can somebody help me with this problem?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/globals.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <% let showing = 0 %>
    <div class="box grid">
        <div class="container_1">
            <% for(let i = 0; i < data.length; i++){ %>
            <div class="item" onclick="setShowing(this.getAttribute('key'), data)" key="<%= i %>">
                <h2><%= data[i].name %></h2>
                <p><%= data[i].gender %>, <%= data[i].nationality %>, <%= data[i].age %></p>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </div>
        <div class="container_2">
            <div class="item_details">
                <h2><%= data[showing].name %></h2>
                <p><%= data[showing].gender %>, <%= data[showing].nationality %>, <%= data[showing].age %></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        
        function setShowing(newValue, data) {
            console.log("updating value:", newValue);
            showing = newValue;

            const nameElement = document.querySelector('.item_2 .item h2');
            const detailElement = document.querySelector('.item_2 .item p');
            nameElement.innerHTML = data[showing].name;
            detailElement.innerHTML = data[showing].gender + ", " + data[showing].nationality + ", " + data[showing].age;
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I was expecting for it to render the data with the index stored in the variable showing. Instead it gave me an error saying it's not defined.
I also tried doing it another way and it would give me an error, but then it wouldn't update any of the data.

The problem
The main problem is that you seem to misunderstand EJS variables. All the variables you pass to the render engine when using res.render(...), ejs.render(...) or any rendering method, are only available during the render process.
I have written a more elaborate explanation about the EJS variables passed to the rendering function on this question, but here's a shorter one:
Imagine we have this EJS template called default.ejs
<!-- html header -->
<body>
  <% let title = "Default page"; %>
  <h1><%= title %></h1>
  <% for(let i in data) { %>
    <div onclick="doSomething(<%= i %>, data)">
      <h2><%= data[i].name %></h2>
      <p><%= data[i].gender %>, <%= data[i].nationality %>, <%= data[i].age %></p>
    </div>
  <% } %>
  <script>
    doSomething(i, data) {
      console.log("Hi I'm", data[i].name, "and I'm", data[i].age, "years old.");
    }
  </script>
</body>
<!-- html footer -->

And send it to the client like so
let data = [
  {name: "GreenSaiko", age: 21, nationality: "IT", gender: "m"},
  {name: "Ludwig", age: 25, nationality: "DE", gender: "m"}
];
APP.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('default', {data: data});
});

The render(...) function then makes the engine render the template, meaning it checks through the template and (in our case with EJS) any part enclosed in EJS tags will be run as JavaScript code with the context of variables we passed to the function, so just data.
This runs without issues and the page renders with the title we defined and our two persons in the data array. But, if you take a look at your DOM with the DevTools (F12), you will see that all the divs around the persons data have the onclick event defined as onclick="doSomething(0, data)" (but instead of 0 each one has their index). This may look fine, “Well yes, the data variable we passed”, but in fact, after the template was rendered and sent to the client, the JavaScript has absolutely no idea what this data variable is. Only the render engine receives those variables to render the template, they are not added to the context of the document itself and thus the client never receives those variables.
Which means your setShowing function will not work properly as the data parameter is undefined.
The solution
To be honest, I'm not quite sure what you want to show with this. It shows the same information as already presented. But seeing you named the class of the inner div item_details I'll assume you want to show more information than there is in the data variable you pass to the render engine.
So, what can you do if the client does not have the data variable?

Use the fetchAPI to send a request to the server for the specific set of data and then display the received data with DOM manipulation.
First, the fetch request would only need an index, so the onclick method would change to
 <div onclick="displayPersonDetails('<%= i %>')">

(Note: I only put the ' around the ejs tags, so the interpreter wouldn't see it as an error, even though it works fine)
In the displayPersonDetails method, you would then make a fetch request to get the data
 <script>
   function displayPersonDetails(i) {
     fetch('/url/to/get/persons/data/'+i, {
       method: 'GET',
       headers: {
         'Conent-Type': 'application/json'
       }
     })
     .then( res => res.json() )
     .then( data => {
       let container = document.querySelector('.item_details');
       let h2 = document.createElement('h2');
       let p = document.createElement('p');
       h2.innerHTML = data.data.name;
       p.innerHTML = data.data.gender + ", " + data.data.nationality + ", " + data.data.age;
       container.innerHTML = "";
       container.appendChild(h2);
       container.appendChild(p);
     })
     .catch( err => console.log(err) );
   }
 </script>

This is just one variation of this. You could also prepare a partial template with the content of the .item_details div, render that on the server with the requested set of data and only send HTML markup back to the client. That would shorten the then() of the fetch request to something like
 let p = document.createElement('p');
 p.innerHTML = data.data;

There are many other ways to do this, it mostly comes down to preference.

Pass the data variable to a <script>.
It is actually possible to assign the variables passed to the render engine to another variable in a <script> tag. I wanted to mention this here because it could provide useful in some cases, but I wouldn't recommend doing so because it exposes all the data to the client.
To assign the variable to another variable, you simply can do <%- JSON.stringify(some_variable) %>. It is important to use the <%- (unescaped value) tags! If we try this with our data variable in the example, it would look like this:
 let data = <%- JSON.stringify(data) %>;
 // or like this if we don't want the interpreter to mark this as an error
 let data = JSON.parse('<%- JSON.stringify(data) %>');

But as mentioned before, this exposes the data to the client. If we were to inspect the rendered page on a browser, this part would look like:
 let data = [{"name":"GreenSaiko","age":21,"nationality":"IT","gender":"m"},{"name":"Ludwig","age":25,"nationality":"DE","gender":"m"}];

Because it obviously outputs the whole variable, as intended. If we were to use <%= (escaped value) tags instead, we would get:
 let data = [{&#34;name&#34;:&#34;GreenSaiko&#34;,&#34;age&#34;:21,&#34;nationality&#34;:&#34;IT&#34;,&#34;gender&#34;:&#34;m&#34;},{&#34;name&#34;:&#34;Ludwig&#34;,&#34;age&#34;:25,&#34;nationality&#34;:&#34;DE&#34;,&#34;gender&#34;:&#34;m&#34;}];

From this point, you could use almost your exact code from the question, with some tweaks, but as said, I wouldn't recommend this.


There are more ways to go about this, e.g., sockets, but if it is for a rather smaller project I would recommend using the fetchAPI. Not only because it is easy and works good, but also because it will provide useful in the future learning how to use this API.
You are welcome to ask me if you have more questions :)
